# How to implement REST web service in Grails handling more request at the same time?

Tags: web-services, rest, grails

I have developed REST web service which is able to accept some data, load an user from database, change it a bit and save it back into the database.

Here is the content of the REST web service:

```
class RespondentController {
  static allowedMethods = [save: "GET"]
  synchronized def save = {
    Campaign.withTransaction { status ->
       User user = User.get(params['userId'])
       // do some changes in users...
       user.save()
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is when there are more requests at the same time. Is there a way how change the web service so it would accept more requests at the same time (it is maybe some configuration stuff)?

```
2011-12-18 10:28:57,808 [http-8080-5] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Exception occurred when processing request: [GET] /my-rest-ws/respondent
Stacktrace follows:
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [my.app.User#1]
        at my.app.UserController$_closure1.doCall(RespondentController.groovy:19)
        at my.app.UserController$_closure1.doCall(RespondentController.groovy)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
2011-12-18 10:29:02,625 [http-8080-5] ERROR events.PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener  - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [my.app.User#1]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1792)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2435)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2335)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2635)
        at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:115)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:168)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.events.PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener.performExecutions(PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener.java:46)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:365)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:147)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor773.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:188)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.orm.hibernate.HibernatePluginSupport$_addTransactionalMethods_closure22.doCall(HibernatePluginSupport.groovy:502)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor666.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureStaticMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureStaticMetaMethod.java:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:148)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:88)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
        at my.app.UserController$_closure1.doCall(UserController.groovy:19)
```

Comment: On a side note. Don't you want the save action to have `PUT` as the allowed method? Just to be in line with the typical [RESTful web services methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services)

Comment: I am forced to use GET, so I had to map GET to save action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new controller is created for each request, so synchronizing the action won't help since it's not shared by concurrent users. Plus it's a Closure (pre 2.0) and a synchronized Closure doesn't make any sense.

If you want to block concurrent edits on an object, lock it in a transaction. Create a service

```
class UserService {

   void updateUser(long userId, ...) {
      User user = User.lock(userId)
      // do some changes in users...
      user.save()
   }
}
```

and inject it into your controller:

```
class RespondentController {

   def userService

   def save = {
      long userId = params['userId'] as Long
      userService.updateUser(userId, ...)
   }
}
```

Comment: _Thanks for explaining synchronization stuff!_ Actually, I don't want to lock it, I want to avoid `StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction`. Maybe I could just remove `withTransaction` row and setup `failOnError` to true. What do you think about that?

Comment: Optimistic locking makes sense in a lot of situations, but this seems like a classic use case for pessimistic locking with `lock()` since you know that there will be concurrent updates. Explicit locking should be avoided in general since it can affect performance, but you need data quality too.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution is this one. It is really working, so I am able to handle hundreds of concurrent accesses to my rest web service:

```
class RespondentController {
    static scope = "singleton"
    static allowedMethods = [save: "GET"]

    def save() {
        long userId = params['userId'] as Long
        User.lock(userId)
        User user = User.get(userId)
        // do changes in domain classes... 
        // and some stuff which should be done (e.g. send an email...) 
        user.save(flush:true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- "`Synchronized`" Does not make sense since `Grails` creates a new instance each call of `controller`
- use :

  `User user = User.lock(userId)`

instead of

```
User.lock(userId)
User user = User.get(userId)
```